# ERROR: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute when trying to use trainer.train() on custom HF dataset?

Tags: dictionary, machine-learning, pytorch, dataset, huggingface-transformers

I have the following model that I am trying to fine-tune (CLIP_ViT + classification head). Here’s my model definition:

```
class CLIPNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, num_labels, pretrained_name="openai/clip-vit-base-patch32", dropout=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_labels = num_labels
        # load pre-trained transformer & processor
        self.transformer = CLIPVisionModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_name)
        self.processor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained(pretrained_name)
        # initialize other layers (head after the transformer body)
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(512, 128, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(p=dropout, inplace=False),
            nn.Linear(128, self.num_labels, bias=True))
        
        def forward(self, inputs, labels=None, **kwargs):
            logits = self.classifier(inputs)
            loss = None
            if labels is not None:
                loss_fct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
                loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))

            return SequenceClassifierOutput(
                loss=loss,
                logits=logits,
            )
```

I also have the following definition for a dataset:

```
class CLIPDataset(nn.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, embeddings, labels):
        self.embeddings = embeddings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {"embeddings": nn.Tensor(self.embeddings[idx])}
        item['labels'] = nn.LongTensor([self.labels[idx]])
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)
```

Note: here I am assuming that the model is fed pre-computed embeddings and does not compute embeddings, I know this is not the right logic if I want to fine-tune the CLIP base model, I am just trying to get my code to work.

Something like this throws an error:

```
model = CLIPNN(num_labels=2)
train_data = CLIPDataset(train_data, y_train)
test_data = CLIPDataset(test_data, y_test)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model, args=training_args, train_dataset=train_data, eval_dataset=test_data
)
trainer.train()
```

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) in
> ----> 1 trainer.train()
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py
> in train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval,
> **kwargs) 1256 self.control = self.callback_handler.on_epoch_begin(args, self.state, self.control)
> 1257 → 1258 for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator): 1259 1260 #
> Skip past any already trained steps if resuming training
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in next(self) 515 if self._sampler_iter is None: 516 self._reset() →
> 517 data = self._next_data() 518 self._num_yielded += 1 519 if
> self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self) 555 def _next_data(self): 556 index =
> self._next_index() # may raise StopIteration → 557 data =
> self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index) # may raise StopIteration 558 if
> self._pin_memory: 559 data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py
> in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index) 45 else: 46 data =
> self.dataset[possibly_batched_index] —> 47 return
> self.collate_fn(data)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py
> in default_data_collator(features, return_tensors) 64 65 if
> return_tensors == “pt”: —> 66 return
> torch_default_data_collator(features) 67 elif return_tensors == “tf”:
> 68 return tf_default_data_collator(features)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py
> in torch_default_data_collator(features) 80 81 if not
> isinstance(features[0], (dict, BatchEncoding)): —> 82 features =
> [vars(f) for f in features] 83 first = features[0] 84 batch = {}
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py
> in (.0) 80 81 if not isinstance(features[0], (dict, BatchEncoding)):
> —> 82 features = [vars(f) for f in features] 83 first = features[0] 84
> batch = {}
>
> TypeError: vars() argument must have dict attribute

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is `Trainer`?

Comment: @Ivan Trainer is the training API provided by HuggingFace: https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/trainer.html

I am getting another error now:

 TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'

Comment: @skidjoe How did you solve this ?

Comment: Also stuck on this one looks like there is not a lot of advice on HF forum or here. I think the answer might be in building a custom data_collator

Comment: Someone had a similar issue on GitHub. They had a hacky solution that involves using a dict instead; it might help: https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/6370#issuecomment-1789403845

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the `label_names` attribute to your `Trainer`

```py
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model, args=training_args, train_dataset=train_data, label_names=['labels'], eval_dataset=test_data
)
```

Comment: label_names is not a valid argument in Trainer. It has to be specified in the TrainingArguments.